# Unable to run clisp on Solaris 10 with opencsw Solaris Package

Tags: software-installation, solaris, libraries, lisp

I have tried to run the Clisp which is already available in opt/csw/bin path
I didn't manage to get it working.

***Expected result:***

To see a prompt.

***Actual results (terminal output):***

- when I tried to run clisp using ./clisp inside the path opt/csw/bin,
  I get the below error.

  # ./clisp

  ld.so.1: lisp.run: fatal: libavcall.so.0: open failed: No such file or directory
  Killed
- I tried to list available library for the package clisp, I get the
  following but no libavcall.so.0 file is present.

  # ldd clisp

  ```
  libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
  libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
  ```

***What I tried to fix the issue:***

- Updated the package, still throws the same error after running ./clisp command.
- Added /opt/csw/bin to the path variable, still the error persists.

***My Observations:***

- I tried to run ldd clisp command on the root path, I get

  # ldd clisp

  ldd: clisp: cannot open file: No such file or directory
- When I tried to run the same command after entering into the path
  opt/csw/bin, I get

  # ldd clisp

  ```
  libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
  libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
  ```

I tried to follow the instructions given in the below link:
https://www.opencsw.org/package/clisp/

Did I miss anything to install clisp so I am getting this error? I am new to clisp. Any help to resolve the issue is appreciated.

Comment: If you run it as a regular user instead of root, do you get the same error?

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue. Yes I get the same error when I run ./clisp command in /opt/csw/bin path as a regular user instead of root.

Comment: In your `/opt/csw/lib` directory, is there a file named something like `libavcall.so.0` ? If not, you may have to install [libavcall1](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWlibavcall1/) from the opencsw repository. If it is there, you should adjust your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include `/opt/csw/lib`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Issue resolved.

I have installed libavcall1 file but the file gave me version 1.0.0 where clisp is expecting 0 version. So I linked the files: 

ln -s /opt/csw/lib/libavcall.so.1.0.0 /opt/csw/lib/libavcall.so.0 
ln -s /opt/csw/lib/libcallback.so.1.0.0 /opt/csw/lib/libcallback.so.0 

This has resolved my issue. Thanks again @MarkPlotnick